# MSAL-Angular is there any event or callback available for signup completed?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

We are using MSAL-Angular in our app. Is there any event or callback available  for user successfully signed up like "msal:loginSuccess"

Comment: What do you mean behind "signed up"?

Comment: After user sign=up in b2c and got redirected to my angular app there I need to know is user done signup or login for some workflow

Comment: In my opinion, there is no such event. MSAL/OAuth base on login. Ugly, but doable - maybe you can compare the login time, with the time of the User entity `createdDateTime` property - using MS Graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the "newUser" claim in the idTokenClaims from the "msal:loginSuccess" response.

```
this.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:loginSuccess', (success) => {
  if(success.idTokenClaims.newUser){
    console.log('this is a new user');
  }
}
```

Here is a sample image from the response:

[image: Here is a sample image from the response]

the "newUser" boolean flag will be returned on login success if this is the first time this user login to the system.